# Pytests import fails after renaming project folder

Tags: python, pytest

I've been struggling for a while with renaming a project folder of a Python project. It was called Foo and I want it to rename it to Bar.

```
Foo/
   /src
        __init__.py
        x.py
   /test
        __init__.py
        x_test.py
   __init__.py
```

became

```
Bar/
   /src
        __init__.py
        x.py
   /test
        __init__.py
        x_test.py
    __init__.py
```

When the project folder was named Foo all my tests passed, but after renaming it to Bar my tests don't work anymore. All imports will raise an `ImportError: no module src.x`.

I **can** import the module when I'm using the python console:

```
$ python
>>> import src.x
```

When I then rename Bar back to Foo and run the test I'll get this error:

```
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test.x' has this __file__ attribute:
  /home/orangetux/projects/Foo/test/x_test.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /home/orangetux/projects/Bar/test/x_test.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

I can fix this by removing all `__pycache__` folders. But now I'm back at the start. A folder named Foo with working test. How do I rename the project folder to Bar and keep working tests?

Answer (score 7):

Delete the python cache (`__pycache__`) and all "compiled" files (ie: *.pyc, *.pyo).

Make sure that your **`__init.py__`** files are not referring to any folder or path.

Comment: Using the `py.cleanup -p` command from the pycmd package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycmd) is convenient for this.

Comment: I have to agree that this issue with python caching is easily resolved by the above comment. Install the pycmd package and use `py.cleanup -p` and renaming directories wont throw errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the presence of `__init__.py` file in your root directory which is unnecessary.

---

If you just remove it, you should be able to run the tests properly, even when you rename the project folder.

```
Bar/
   /src
        __init__.py
        x.py
   /test
        __init__.py
        x_test.py
    __init__.py  -------------> REMOVE THIS FILE
```