# Pytest Discovery Error in VSCode after renaming folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest

I have *pytest* configured and working in VSCode, with automatic test discovery enabled.

But renaming a folder in the project that contains tests breaks both those tests and auto-discovery, instead producing a `Pytest Discovery Error`.  How can I get the Testing to fully refresh – removing tests under the old folder name and adding those in the new name?

Simple steps to reproduce problem:

1. Under project folder `hello` is a folder `foo` containing `x.py` and `test_x.py`.
2. Open the VSCode Testing sidebar and configure to run pytest.
3. Now the Testing pane shows the test hierarchy `hello >> foo >> test_x.py >> test_*`
4. In the VSCode Explorer pane rename `foo` to `bar`.
5. Refresh Testing >> Test Explorer, and/or re-run all tests.

Result:

- None of the tests under `hello >> foo` work because there is no `hello/foo`.
- I can't get `hello >> bar >> ...` to appear in the Testing pane.
- Test Explorer also contains a `Pytest Discovery Error [hello]` (with details pasted below).

How can I force the Testing configuration to refresh so that it removes the `hello >> foo` tests and adds the `hello >> bar` tests?

---

Verbose output after renaming `foo` to `bar` and refreshing/re-running tests:

```
Python interpreter path: ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -c "import pytest"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear foo
cwd: .
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear foo
cwd: .
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear foo
cwd: .
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pytest --rootdir . --override-ini junit_family=xunit1 --junit-xml=~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13840MhzPL4CPuKOe.xml ./foo
cwd: .
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pytest --rootdir . --override-ini junit_family=xunit1 --junit-xml=~\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-13840ITbhhDmK8Ah1.xml
cwd: .
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe ~\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\testing_tools\run_adapter.py discover pytest -- --rootdir . -s --cache-clear foo
cwd: .
[ERROR 2022-8-18 12:2:6.129]: Error discovering pytest tests:
 [n [Error]: ============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.2, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: c:\Users\Me\VSCode\hello
collected 0 items

========================= no tests collected in 0.00s =========================
ERROR: file or directory not found: foo
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue. I read on some threads the idea just to remove all the cache files (especially `__pycache__` and `.pytest_cache`). See [Pytests import fails after renaming project folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21818958/320036) for details.

But I figured out where the problem was without removing anything. There is a file `settings.json` in the `.vscode` folder. So, it contained an entry `python.testing.unittestArgs` with the old name of the renamed <del>project</del> folder. After I updated that entry VSCode works as expected again.

So you should try both:

- Remove `**/__pycache__`, `**/*.pyc`, and `.pytest_cache`
- Check `.vscode/settings.json` for outdated config.

I hope that helps!